# How to update AWS cloudfront distribution via Java code

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, aws-java-sdk

I want to update aws CloudFront distribution via Java code. Simplifying the question I wanted to add CNAMEs dynamically via Java code. I have gone through multiple documents but I am not able to find exact solution. Can someone help me out?

Comment: There is [updateDistribution](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CloudFront.html#updateDistribution-property) where you can update CNAMEs.

Comment: Thanks @Marcin I'll look into it.